# Difference in meaning of ' Old habits die hard.' Vs 'Old habits hardly die.'

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the difference in the meaning of these two sentences

1. Old habits die hard.
2. Old habits hardly die.

Are they both grammatically correct?

According to me, the first statement says that it is difficult to get rid of old habits whereas second says that the probability of losing your old habit is very less.

Comment: Your question would look better if you included some of your own research efforts. Both phrases mean the same thing, are grammatically correct and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy: I thought hard about your comment. All I can say is: *I hardly think so!**

Comment: *Old habits die hard* is a well known phrase or saying. The other one isn't, and means something rather different, at which @FumbleFingers hints.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - 
It's hard to tell which part of my comment you disagree with. I can hardly formulate an appropriate response for it. I do agree that #1 is the proper idiom. But I have heard people using #2 (Old Habits seldom die and other variations in InE). It may be wrong but it is not unheard of.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy: They're *hardly* comparable, since idiomatically that usage means [not at all; scarcely](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hardly), whereas the standard version of the idiom means that killing off an old habit [involves a great deal of effort, energy, or persistence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hard?s=t). If you've often heard #2, perhaps you associate with a lot of non-native speakers, but you don't bother to set them straight.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yes, of course! I associate with a lot of non-native English speakers. That doesn't stop me from trying to perfect my English as much as possible. You could probably correct 10, 20 or even a hundred people. But there are just too many learners and budding speakers of English that mistakes are bound to happen. And I have better things to do than nitpick on every wrong usage ever made. (..to be continued)

Comment: (..continued from above) 
Perhaps, that's how *Indianims* are born and passed on across generations. As I have commented earlier, these type of usages might be frowned upon by Native speakers, but they do seem to get the message across when spoken within non-native speakers. So, let's not allow a post to generate hard feelings between us. This question is (most probably) from a non-native speaker of InE. I can clearly see the confusion. I hope you do too.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy: I can see how someone unfamiliar with the idiom might think they're "equivalent", but it's worth noting that Google Books claims 39,000 results for [Old habits die hard](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Old+habits+die+hard%22), against just 8 for [Old habits hardly die](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Old+habits+hardly+die%22) (most of which seem to be from nns).

Answer (score 1):

***Old habits die hard*** is an idiom.

"Old habits hardly die" is not an idiom. It sounds kind of weird. You might be confusing it with "In Hoover, Humbert and Hempville, heavy hurricanes hardly ever happen half-heartedly," which is an old Celtic saying.

Answer (score 1):

> *Old habits die hard*:
>   used for saying that it is difficult to change a way of behaving that someone has had for many years - [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/old-habits-die-hard)

*Old habits hardly die* means that they don't often die. That is, old habits tend to survive.

The first is idiomatic as @Ricky mentioned. The second is perhaps a humorous reply or excuse to say that the first is an understatement - the task well nigh impossible!